# Connecting to Azure service bus using spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-spring-cloud

I am trying to follow microsoft documentation on connecting to azure service bus using spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/using-service-bus-in-spring-applications

Pom file :

```
 <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
            <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.9.1</spring-cloud-azure.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Azure Service bus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>7.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java code:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Slf4j
public class ProcessorClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ServiceBusRecordMessageListener processMessage() {
        return context -> {
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = context.getMessage();
            log.info("Processing message. Id: %s, Sequence #: %s. Contents: %s%n", message.getMessageId(),
                    message.getSequenceNumber(), message.getBody());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceBusErrorHandler processError() {
        return context -> {
            log.error("Error when receiving messages from namespace: '%s'. Entity: '%s'%n",
                    context.getFullyQualifiedNamespace(), context.getEntityPath());
        };
    }
}
```

application.properties value:

```
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.namespace=Endpoint=sb://sbns-...
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-name=data-preprod
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.processor.subscription-name=data-preprod
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-type=topic
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder$ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilder]: Factory method 'serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder' threw exception with message: Subscription cannot be null.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Subscription cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to instantiate [com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder$ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilder]: Factory method 'serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder' threw exception with message: Subscription cannot be null.

- As per my observation, this error occurred because you have used `entity-type=topic` instead of `entity-type=Queue` in `application.properties`.
- I got the same error when I tried with **Topic** but worked as expected with **Queue type**.

I have followed the same [MSDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010883/connecting-to-azure-service-bus-using-spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus) to send messages to Service Bus Queue using Spring Boot Application.

**Steps followed:**

- Created a Service Bus NameSpace and Queue.
- Assigned the below roles to my user in the service Bus.

```
1. Azure Service Bus Data Owner
2. Azure Service Bus Data Receiver
3. Azure Service Bus Data Sender
```

- Created a Spring Boot Application with Maven.

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus</artifactId>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**ServiceBusProcessorClientConfiguration.java:**

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ServiceBusProcessorClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ServiceBusRecordMessageListener processMessage() {
        return context -> {
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = context.getMessage();
            System.out.printf("Processing message. Id: %s, Sequence #: %s. Contents: %s%n", message.getMessageId(),
                    message.getSequenceNumber(), message.getBody());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceBusErrorHandler processError() {
        return context -> {
            System.out.printf("Error when receiving messages from namespace: '%s'. Entity: '%s'%n",
                    context.getFullyQualifiedNamespace(), context.getEntityPath());
        };
    }
}
```

**DemoController.java:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient;

    public DemoApplication(ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient) {
        this.senderClient = senderClient;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        senderClient.sendMessage(new ServiceBusMessage("Hello, World!"));
        System.out.printf("Sent a message to the queue");
        senderClient.close();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.namespace=<ServiceBusNamespace>
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-name=<ServiceBusQueueName>
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-type=queue
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.processor.auto-startup=false
```

- **Able to send the messages to Queue:**

**Portal:**

[image]